# What's the effective difference between a Steam Wallet Code and a Steam Gift Card

Tags: steam

I read the Steam description of the difference in their knowledge base, but it didn't actually clarify anything for me. In both cases you end up with a code that one can use to add money to one's Steam wallet, correct?

I have a slight preference for a wallet code instead of a gift card because I noticed that the sites that are selling wallet codes online seem to have a $30 denomination, which is what I prefer. Gift cards only come in $20 and $50. I've noticed that the sites selling wallet codes seem to all be overseas for some reason, which makes me a little bit leery as to their legitimacy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To my knowledge, the gift cards are like your normal gift card but the wallet codes you purchase and they just put the code on your receipt (at least at GameStop). They should both do the same thing. Don't buy the codes from any untrusted source as Steam scams are quite common nowadays, just get the legitimate gift card and play it safe in my opinion.